# Visual Basic CMD command from textbox input

Tags: vb.net, shell, command-prompt

I want to try something,this isn't the official project.
So the users adds the webpage and lets say we name it %1 the code take that and the output is "ping %1" and press enter key.

What I've done so far

```
Public Class Form3


    Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim textvar As String = TextBox1.Text
        Shell("CMD.exe")
        SendKeys.Send("ping") 'textvar') '{ENTER}')

    End Sub
End Class
```

The output of that is an empty cmd window or crash.Any idea on how to fix that?

Update: Also i tried

```
SendKeys.Send("ping") 'textvar')
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
```

but the output is 3 cmd windows 1 of them empty the other 2 split the "ping" word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to send keystrokes (which can be problematic), just call `ping` as a parameter to `CMD`.

```
Shell("CMD.EXE /K PING " & textvar)
```

The `/K` parameter keeps the `CMD` window open after the `PING` command finishes.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked!Sorry for the delay of answering but I was away.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim textvar As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim Command As String
Command = "Ping" & " " & textvar
Shell("cmd /k" & Command, 1, True)
```

This should be right